# How to get the last div element in c #?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There is such a piece of html.

[image]

I need to get text from the last div element. For example, at the moment I get the ninth element like this:

```
var textmsg = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='main']/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[9]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/span[1]/span")).Text;
            string textmsgS = Convert.ToString(textmsg);
            Console.WriteLine(textmsgS);
```

But as I said, I need to get exactly the last element. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this,i hope, by this way your issue will fix

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/div[last()]")).click();
```

or by using css selector you can try like this

You can have an array list of elements and then select the last element by:

```
List<WebElement> elements= driver.findElements(By.css("css"));

 element = elements.get(list.size() - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I edited and thats work `var textmsg = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='main']/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[last()]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/span[1]/span")).Text;`